# QB_OFFMODE_ALARM unexpected components

Tags: installation, htc, ota-update, htc-one-m8

OTA Update Failure - HTC ONE M8 (tmobile)
Updating from 4.4.2 to 4.4.3

Update gets about 25% during install and then fails. If I switch to recovery I can see the error which states:

*"Unexpected Components in QB_OFFMODE_ALARM"*

I spoke to HTC support and they had me try wiping cache, manual updating, etc.. all with the same result.

Any ideas?

ALso I have rooted my phone and attempted to load using sideload and other methods with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply an OTA update to a rooted phone. You need to download a complete stock ROM and flash it from your PC.

Comment: I rooted it after all of the failed attempts with HTC support. Thanks for the info though. I will find a stock Rom.